# How to set Text position steady?

Tags: three.js

With the help of `TextGeometry`, I am drawing text around meshes. `PerspectiveCamera` is in steady mode, My cube is moving itself in the scene. How can text take a look to the object rotation?
[Check this](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Labeled-Geometry.html) I want to do like this same.

```
 var storeCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, $domElement.innerWidth() / $domElement.innerHeight(), 1, 10000);
 dist = (largestSide - 0) / 2 + (largestSide - 0) / (2 * Math.tan(storeCamera.fov * Math.PI / 360));
 storeCamera.position.z = dist;

  var axisHelperScene = new THREE.Scene();
  var axisHelperCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, $domElement.find('.axis-helper').innerWidth() / $domElement.find('.axis-helper').innerHeight(), 1, 10000);
  axisHelperCamera.position.z = 350;

  var axisHelperRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
     antialias: true, alpha: true
  });
  axisHelperRenderer.setSize($domElement.find('.axis-helper').innerWidth(), $domElement.find('.axis-helper').innerHeight());
  $domElement.find('.axis-helper').append(axisHelperRenderer.domElement);

  var directionX = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
  var directionY = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
  var directionZ = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
  var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  var length = 150;
  var color = 0x4a4f65;
  var headLength = 45;
  var headWidth = 30;

  // creating axes
  var arrowHelperX = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionX, origin, length, color, headLength, headWidth);
  arrowHelperX.line.material.linewidth = 4; 
  var arrowHelperY = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionY, origin, length, color, headLength, headWidth);
  arrowHelperX.line.material.linewidth = 4; 
  var arrowHelperZ = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionZ, origin, length, color, headLength, headWidth);
  arrowHelperX.line.material.linewidth = 4; 

  // origin sphere
  var axisSphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 40, 40, 40),
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x4a4f65 }));

  var axisGroup = new THREE.Group();
  axisGroup.add(arrowHelperX);
  axisGroup.add(arrowHelperY);
  axisGroup.add(arrowHelperZ);
  axisGroup.add(axisSphere);

  axisGroup.rotation.x = 0.60;
  axisGroup.rotation.y = -0.50;

  // #region Adding axis labels
  var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
  var jsonFont = String.format("{0}Scripts/threejs/json/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json", GetResourceFromClient("RootUrl"));
  fontLoader.load(jsonFont, function (theFont) {
     var xLabel = new THREE.TextGeometry("X", {
        font: theFont,
        size: 35,
        height: 10,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelThickness: 1,
        bevelSize: 1,
        bevelEnabled: true
     });

     var yLabel = new THREE.TextGeometry("Y", {
        font: theFont,
        size: 35,
        height: 10,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelThickness: 1,
        bevelSize: 1,
        bevelEnabled: true
     });

     var zLabel = new THREE.TextGeometry("Z", {
        font: theFont,
        size: 35,
        height: 10,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelThickness: 1,
        bevelSize: 1,
        bevelEnabled: true
     });

     var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0x4a4f65
     });

     var xMesh = new THREE.Mesh(xLabel, textMaterial);
     xMesh.position.x = 160;
     xMesh.position.y = -10;
     axisGroup.add(xMesh);

     var yMesh = new THREE.Mesh(yLabel, textMaterial);
     yMesh.position.x = -10;
     yMesh.position.z = -160;
     axisGroup.add(yMesh);

     var zMesh = new THREE.Mesh(zLabel, textMaterial);
     zMesh.position.x = -10;
     zMesh.position.y = 160;
     axisGroup.add(zMesh);
  });
  // #endregion Adding axis labels

 function render() {
     storeRenderer.render(storeScene, storeCamera);
     axisHelperRenderer.render(axisHelperScene, axisHelperCamera);
     requestAnimFrame(render);
  }
```

Comment: Please show your code. You can also edit this fiddle and demonstrate your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/

Comment: @WestLangley I just added code here. Please have a look and http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Labeled-Geometry.html I want to achieve as same as in this link.

Comment: If you want them always to face camera then try `mesh.lookAt(camera.position)` [lookAt example](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_lookat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a TextGeometry for the axis labels a sprite could be an option

```
  var xLabel = makeTextSprite(" X ", { fontsize: 100, borderColor: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1.0 }, backgroundColor: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 0.8 } , borderThickness: 5});
  xLabel.position.set(150, 0, 0);
  axisGroup.add(xLabel);

  // creates a THREE.Sprite object with the given text and parameters
  function makeTextSprite(theMessage, theParameters) {
     if (theParameters === undefined) theParameters = {
     };

     var fontface = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("fontface") ?
        theParameters["fontface"] : "Arial";

     var fontsize = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("fontsize") ?
        theParameters["fontsize"] : 18;

     var borderThickness = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("borderThickness") ?
        theParameters["borderThickness"] : 4;

     var borderColor = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("borderColor") ?
        theParameters["borderColor"] : {
           r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1.0
        };

     var backgroundColor = theParameters.hasOwnProperty("backgroundColor") ?
        theParameters["backgroundColor"] : {
           r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 1.0
        };

     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     context.font = "Bold " + fontsize + "px " + fontface;

     // get size data (height depends only on font size)
     var metrics = context.measureText(theMessage);
     var textWidth = metrics.width;

     // background color
     context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + backgroundColor.r + "," + backgroundColor.g + ","
                            + backgroundColor.b + "," + backgroundColor.a + ")";
     // border color
     context.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + borderColor.r + "," + borderColor.g + ","
                            + borderColor.b + "," + borderColor.a + ")";

     context.lineWidth = borderThickness;
     roundRect(context, borderThickness / 2, borderThickness / 2, textWidth + borderThickness, fontsize * 1.4 + borderThickness, 6);
     // 1.4 is extra height factor for text below baseline: g,j,p,q.

     // text color
     context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)";

     context.fillText(theMessage, borderThickness, fontsize + borderThickness);

     // canvas contents will be used for a texture
     var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas)
     texture.needsUpdate = true;

     var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial(
           {
              map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false
           });
     var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
     sprite.scale.set(100, 50, 1.0);
     return sprite;
  }

  // function for drawing rounded rectangles
  function roundRect(ctx, x, y, w, h, r) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);
     ctx.lineTo(x + w - r, y);
     ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + r);
     ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - r);
     ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h);
     ctx.lineTo(x + r, y + h);
     ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - r);
     ctx.lineTo(x, y + r);
     ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + r, y);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();
  }
```

}